# JOOQ:Returning Multiple User Defined Objects

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

Is it possible to fetch *multiple user* defined *Objects* with *Jooq*. For example can I do something like this?

```
Factory create = new Factory(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
     create.select(AUTHOR,BOOK).from(BOOK).
    JOIN(AUTHOR).ON(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID)).fetch();
```

AS we Do,

```
    create.select(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID,BOOK.BOOK_ID,BOOK.BOOK_NAME).from(BOOK).
JOIN(AUTHOR).ON(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID)).fetch();
```

Error Message :

> Error:(52, 16) java: no suitable method found for select(...)

AUTHOR, BOOK are Tables in Database and JOOQ auto code generator has been used to generate Classes for them.

Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: @auth private  Thanks for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Result.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#into-org.jooq.Table-) for this:

```
Result<Record> result =
create.select()
      .from(BOOK)
      .join(AUTHOR).
      .on(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
      .fetch();

BookRecord book = result.into(BOOK);
AuthorRecord author = result.into(AUTHOR);
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas for help!!